# I have facing below mention error in new version of python 3.8. Can any suggest how to solve it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras_init_.py", line 3, in
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_init_.py", line 41, in
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_init_.py", line 40, in
from tensorflow.python.eager import context

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in
raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "F:\Prognica Work\Application Code\unet_keras-master\New_UNET.py", line 20, in
from keras.models import Model, load_model

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras_init_.py", line 5, in
raise ImportError(

ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: Have you checked the URL listed? Is there any mention of errors importing `pywrap`? (*Hint: there is*) Have you looked to see if they apply to your case?

Comment: Try upgrading your Tensorflow package via `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`.

Comment: You might be facing this issue because either you are running 32-bit python or 32-bit OS and does your CPU supports AVX instructions? Also You need to ensure have the latest MSVC redistributable and that the Python binary is installed from official sources, not from Windows marketplace.For more information you can refer [system requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements).Thanks!.